# King of Tokyo (2016 version): Psychic Probe

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In the 2nd edition of King of Tokyo (2016 version), the *Psychic Probe* Power Card states:

> Psychic Probe (Keep): You can reroll a die of your choice after the last Roll of each other Monster. If you reroll [heart dice symbol], discard this card.

There are also three Power Cards that let you change your own dice after the Roll Dice step:

> Stretchy (Keep): Before resolving your dice, you can spend 2 [energy symbol] to change one of your dice to any result.
>
> Plot Twist (Keep): Before resolving your dice, you may change one die to any result. Discard when used.
>
> Herd Culler (Keep): You can change one of your dice to [1 dice symbol] each turn.

Does this mean that Psychic Probe must be used before *Plot Twist*, *Stretchy*, or *Herd Culler*?

For example, if a player uses *Plot Twist*, *Stretchy*, *Herd Culler*, or any combination thereof before another player with *Psychic Probe* has called out the reroll, does that then mean that the player with *Psychic Probe* has forfeited the ability to reroll that turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Richard Garfield the game's designer, the timing of Psychic Probe interacting with cards such as Plot Twist, Stretchy, or Herd Culler is reactive - one player must commit to the use of their card, then the other must decide to use their card - there is no specific order in which these cards will always resolve and if neither player opts to use their card then the existing roll stands.

The clarification for this can be found [here](http://www.threedonkeys.com/blog/archives/722#comment-3613) in the comments on one of Richards podcasts.

Obviously based on the date and content of the podcast, this was intended as a clarification for first edition, but unless the rules have changed significantly on any of the cards (which as far as I can see, they haven't) it would still apply for second edition.

Comment: That feels very unfair. In a game with experienced players, Plot Twist, Stretchy, and Herd Culler become almost useless once Psychic Probe is in play. Can we not interpret the "last Roll" in the definition of Psychic Probe in such a way that the Psychic Probe must be played before Plot Twist, Stretchy, or Herd Culler. Once a player decides to use any of the latter, the player with Psychic Probe has forfeited his reroll?

Comment: I see very little difference in the level of fairness compared to a player choosing to use Psychic Probe on someone else, just to have the active player then use one of those listed cards to undo the change. If you really must have an order of process for the cards, use the suggestion Richard makes in that comment: the players must decide whether or not to use their cards in order around the table from the active player. You may still think it unfair, but at least it is consistently unfair.

Comment: Also remember that it still deters the player with the Psychic Probe if you change the die result with one of those cards to a heart.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I guess I was still being salty from a previous game. "Also remember that it still deters the player with the Psychic Probe if you change the die result with one of those cards to a heart." Does this actually count as a rerolled heart? On the card it says, when YOU reroll a heart..

Comment: Ignore that bit, late night and misinterpreting the wording above. The exact wording for Psychic Probe that I know is: "If the reroll is [heart symbol] discard this card" which is much less ambiguous.